# can't connect to sql azure database using monotouch

Tags: sql, azure, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a iphone project using c# and monotouch.
I need to use an SQL Azure database.
My problem is that I cant seem to get connected using monotouch.
I can make the code below work fine in a native console application built on a windows 8 machine using visual studio 2012.
But, when I try to port it over to an imac and use monodevelop/monotouch my iphone app crashes.
The error I get is:

System.NotImplementedException: SSL encryption for data sent between client and server is not implemented.

I google around a bit and found a bug report that seems to describe my exact issue [here](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2011-February/109539.html). I noticed its almost two years old so i'm not sure if this would still be unimplemented.

So, I tried changing the value of StringBuilder.Encrypt = true; to false.
But, it still crashes and I get the error:

Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsInternalException: Server closed the connection. ---> System.IO.IOException: Connection lost

in either case the app crashes when conn.Open(); is called.

I'm pretty stuck, and I don't have a choice but to use SQL Azure.
So, if anyone could suggest a solution or work around for my issue, I'd appreciate it greatly.
thanks in advance!

```
        string userName = "<username>@<myservername>";
        string password = "<password>";
        string dataSource = "<myservername>.database.windows.net";
        string databaseName = "<dbname>";

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder;
        connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connStringBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
        connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
        connStringBuilder.Encrypt = true;
        connStringBuilder.TrustServerCertificate = false;
        connStringBuilder.UserID = userName;
        connStringBuilder.Password = password;


        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (connStringBuilder.ToString())) {

            conn.Open();

            using (IDbCommand dbcmd = conn.CreateCommand()){
                string sql = "Select client_username from dbo.client;";
                dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
                using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader()){
                    while( reader.Read() ){
                        string username = (string) reader["client_username"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it is a really bad idea to expose your database server directly to the internet.  The preferred method is to have some sort of (web)service layer running that allows very controlled access to your data.  Also, that bug is still open.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Did you change Azure database firewall settings so that your iPhone is in the allowed range?

Answer (score 3):

SSL for SqlConnection class is not implemented.   See [SqlConnection.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs#L819-L823)

And as Azure requires an encrypted connection you'll have to do some workaround.  For example you could create a web role and expose a web service which executes the SQL on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

try using a simple string as your connection string:

```
        connStr = "Server=tcp:<server_here>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<db_name_here>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;UserID=<user_name_here>@<server_name_here>;Password=<password_here>";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (connStr)) {

            conn.Open();

            using (IDbCommand dbcmd = conn.CreateCommand()){
                string sql = "Select client_username from dbo.client;";
                dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
                using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader()){
                    while( reader.Read() ){
                        string username = (string) reader["client_username"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Note differences - use Server, Database.  Once you get the connection string correct, you can use try the ConnectionStringBuilder and see if you get the exact same output.  BUt its easier to just use a string if you have one that works.

Comment: I removed the the SqlConnectionStringBuilder code and tried to use a plain string. I played around with the string without success. But, I still get the error - System.NotImplementedException: SSL encryption for data sent between client and server is not implemented. So, I feel like I'm trying to do something that mono can't do. could that be the case? would there be a work around?

Comment: It was a good suggestion, to reduce the repro - but it still didnt work for me in mono