# Running .NET application with Mono on Rasberry Pi. Failing to connect to Azure SQL, SSL encryption

Tags: c#, sql, azure, ssl, mono

When I try to connect to a Windows Azure SQL database with my .NET application on my Raspberry Pi with Mono I'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NotImplementedException: SSL encryption for data sent between client
and server is not implemented.
```

And the code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:ip,1433;Database=db;User ID=user@IP;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO db (temp) values (10)";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

All works just fine on Windows.

Why am I receiving the Unhandled Exception on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2):

Because Encryption is implemented yet on Mono [SqlConnection class](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs). Search for `encrypt` - it is still in the "MonoTODO" list.

I wonder however why you don't get the raised NotImplementedException...

Answer (score 1):

As the exception message states is SSL encryption for SQL connections [not implemented in Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs#L819-L823). Unless the Mono team implements it in an upcoming release you simply can't use that feature and need to find a workaround. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14075667/3165741) could help in that regard.

> "All works just fine on Windows."

Starting a .NET aplication by simply calling the executable runs it with the Microsoft .NET CLR and not with Mono. Given [Mono is installed](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Windows) you should be able to reproduce your problem on windows by starting your application from the command line with

```
mono yourapp.exe
```